# How do I process an Avro array of union'd types in Java?

Tags: java, avro

I have an Avro schema defined using IDL that looks similar to the following:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
  record Gizmo {
    string name;
    int cost;
    int weight;
  }

  record Gadget {
    string name;
    int cost;
    double width;
    double height;
  }

  record Order {
    long id;
    array<union{Gizmo, Gadget}> items;
  }
}
```

I'm using auto-generated Java classes from this schema. There are many more types than just Gizmos and Gadgets that can be in the items array, but let's stipulate that all will have a name and a cost.

In my understanding, there's no way to specify inheritance for Avro records, so `getItems()` on the Order object will necessarily give me `List<Object>`. That said, I'd like something with a little more context and type-safety; so far I have come up with three approaches, but none of them seem quite palatable.

**Approach 1:** Perform an unchecked cast to `List<SpecificRecord>` (actually a cast to `List`, and then another cast to `List<SpecificRecord>` because of how generics work) and use `get(int field)`, knowing that name and cost will be fields 1 and 2, respectively. Once I get those, I have to cast them to the appropriate types as well. This seems incredibly fragile.

**Approach 2:** Iterate over the items array, and cast each item individually. I could cast to `SpecificRecord` and use indexed get as in the first approach, or perform a series of `instanceof` checks and then get fields by name. This is either fragile or laborious.

**Approach 3:** Write my own classes that implement `SpecificRecord` and have a proper class hierarchy. This loses the benefits of having auto-generated code, but also seems to be the most robust option, but also very laborious.

Which of these is the best? Or is there a better option?

Comment: Do you have control over the code that generates the Java classes? Or could you post-process its output?

Comment: I'm using the org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin to do the source generation. Since it's open source, I probably can modify the plugin. Not too excited about post-processing the generated sources, since those happen as part of the continuous integration builds.

Comment: It seems to me that having the records turn into Java classes is getting in the way, and it might be better if you could deal with the data in e.g. JSON or XML format. If that is not possible, have you considered reflection?

Comment: @Patricia The data is stored using the avro binary schema on disk, so XML or JSON is probably a no-go. I've thought about reflection - `item.getClass().getMethod("getName").invoke(item)` will get the name field out of anything that has one, at the cost of potentially throwing lots of exceptions and completely subverting the compiler.

Comment: It would not be so bad if you put it in a method, and did the checks rather than taking exceptions. When I was asking about post-processing I was thinking of creating an interface that has the getName and getCost methods, and sneaking an "implements Named" into each declaration.